# Frontend and Backend with express

Tags: node.js, express

Currently i'm working on a web application with express.js. I want to have a frontend and backend. The frontend should show some contents from a database, in the backend i want to create this contents (similar as a cms).

I started with this folder structure:

```
app/
  ├── frontend/
  │     ├── public //Javascript, css & images only for frontend
  │     ├── views //Frontend jade templates
  │     └── client.js
  │
  ├── backend/
  │     ├── public //Only backend css & stuff
  │     └── views //Backend templates
  │     └── core.js
  │
  └── server.js //Starts the whole application
```

The server.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var config = require('../app/config.json')[app.get('env')];

var backend = require('./backend/core');
var frontend = require('./frontend/client');

app.use(backend);
app.use(frontend);

app.set('port', config.port || 3000);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('Server listening on port ' + app.get('port') + ' in ' + app.get('env') + ' mode');
});
```

the client.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('layout', {title: 'Frontpage'});
});

app.get('/about', function(req, res) {
    res.render('layout', {title: 'About us'});
});

module.exports = app;
```

and the core.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    res.render('layout', {title: 'Login'});
});

app.get('/login/dashboard', function(req, res) {
    res.render('layout', {title: 'Dashboard'});
});

module.exports = app;
```

express.js loads the right templates but not the right stylesheet. For **every** route the backend stylesheet is loaded.

```
localhost:3000/about
```

should load the stylesheet in

```
frontend/public/css/
```

and

```
localhost:3000/login
```

should load the css in

```
backend/public/css/
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: Use firebug to see if its loading all the different stylesheets. If it is, then the problem is in your views and not the server. I also like to address the poor use of nomenclature here. Everything inside `public` is usually considered the "front-end". Node and Express are back-end, server technologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue that the backend stylesheet is served by express is a consequence of how express handles requests in conjunction with your application architecture.

A web browser requests a stylesheet **/css/site.css** express accepts this request and processes all middleware and routers. Since you set up your main app like this

```
app.use(backend);
app.use(frontend);
```

The backend app first handles the request. Since you've registered the static middleware in your backend app

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

the stylesheet **/css/site.css** is served from your backend app if this stylesheet exists. This happens for every middleware and route. So any route or asset (css, image) that is requested by a client will be first processed by your backend app. As a consequence routes and assets in the backend app will "hide" routes and assets in your frontend app if they are served via the same route.

A simple solution to your problem would be that you're not serving backend and frontend apps from your main app but to start two express apps in `server.js`:

```
var config = require('../app/config.json')[process.env.NODE_ENV];

var backend = require('./backend/core');
backend.set('port', config.backend.port || 3000);

var backendServer = backend.listen(backend.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('Backend server listening on port ' + backend.get('port') + ' in ' + backend.get('env') + ' mode');
});

var frontend = require('./frontend/client');
frontend.set('port', config.frontend.port || 3001);

var frontendServer = frontend.listen(frontend.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('Frontend server listening on port ' + frontend.get('port') + ' in ' + frontend.get('env') + ' mode');
});
```